# Practice makes perfect OR Practice makes perfection OR Practice makes sth/smb perfect?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The verb *make* is used in various sentence patterns as follows.

> 1. SVO = She made some coffee.
> 2. SVOC (Adjective Complement) = Music makes me happy.
> 3. SVOC (Noun Complement) = They made her the team captain for the coming year.
> 4. SV(iO) (dO) = The chef made him a special cake.
> 5. SVO+PP with *for* = I’ve made an appointment for you at the dentist’s.
> 6. SVO+AC/NC+PP with *for* = He made life difficult for me.

All these example sentences are from the "Cambridge Dictionary's" [**English Grammar Today**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/make), and all of them show the presence of an *object* after the verb *make*.

The question is: Why does the saying/idiomatic phrase ***Practice makes perfect*** not take an object after *make*? Or, Should it not be *perfection* (a noun) after *make* instead of *perfect* (an adjective)?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the saying as being a general statement about things, thus you can plug anything in. "Music practice makes music perfect." Etc. In more mathematical terms "For all x, x practice makes x perfect". It doesn't give a specific x specifically because it's not an assertion about a particular x, it's a statement about all x. It's a shortened form of "practicing something makes that something perfect". It's like how "power corrupts" can be analyzed as a shortened form of "a person having power corrupts that person" or "imitation is the sincerest form of flattery" can be analyzed as a shortened form of "imitating someone is the sincerest form of flattering that person". In none of these sayings is an object required; the object is a "wild card", so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is (or was originally) a word-for-word translation from the Latin ***uses promptos facit*** (use makes perfect).

Source (one of many): https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/12/messages/86.html

Comment: I don’t know where the misspelling originated (it seems to have spread far and wide, so it may go back to John Adams who seems to have popularised the phrase in English), but the Latin word is ***usus***. _Uses_ is definitely not a word in Latin. The trouble here is that the literal meaning of _usus promptum/promptos facit_ is not really that close to ‘practice makes perfect’: it means ‘use makes [you] ready/prepared/quick’. So it’s not a very word-for-word translation at all, and there’s no real reason they shouldn’t have substituted a noun instead. ->

Comment: -> Especially when you consider that [lots of other languages](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practice_makes_perfect) use a noun instead, saying ‘practice makes the master’.

Answer (score 0):

"Practice makes perfect" is a phrase that is hundreds of years old, dating back as far as the 1550s. Like dozens of other phrases or proverbs with a long history, it doesn't necessarily make 100% sense when analysed, but presumably did at the time!